# "[ERROR] {omitted} module jdk.compiler does not "opens com.sun.tools.javac.processing" to unnamed module @73ad993b" while using Maven in EclIpse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to full compile a project in Eclipse using Maven 3.8.3, but every time I do so the process fails and this line comes up in the console:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project fastjson: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Unable to make field private com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoveredProcs accessible: module jdk.compiler does not "opens com.sun.tools.javac.processing" to unnamed module @73ad993b -> [Help 1]
```

The reason why I'm here is beacuse when I launch the same command in cmd (I'm in Windows) the goal testCompile not only does not fail, but Maven is even able to perform all the test in the project:
[execution of maven in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMFYP.png)

**NOTE**: don't look at the test result, I still have to put my hands on them!

The actual command passed is: `mvn clean install`.
I appreciate any help I can get.

**EDIT**
This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
    <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.79</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>fastjson</name>
    <description>Fastjson is a JSON processor (JSON parser + JSON generator) written in Java</description>

    <url>https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson</url>
    <inceptionYear>2012</inceptionYear>

    <properties>
        <junit.version>4.13.1</junit.version>
        <gpg.skip>true</gpg.skip>
        <javadoc.skip>true</javadoc.skip>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jdk.version>1.5</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <url>https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson</url>
        <connection>scm:git:https://git@github.com/alibaba/fastjson.git</connection>
    </scm>

    <organization>
        <name>Alibaba Group</name>
        <url>https://github.com/alibaba</url>
    </organization>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>wenshao</id>
            <name>wenshao</name>
            <email>szujobs@hotmail.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>axmanwang</id>
            <name>axmanwang</name>
            <email>iamaxman@hotmail.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>kimmking</id>
            <name>kimmking</name>
            <email>kimmking@163.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>Victor Zeng</id>
            <name>Victor Zeng</name>
            <email>Victor.Zxy@outlook.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>Neil Dong</id>
            <name>Neil Dong</name>
            <email>email_dsl@163.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <name>李恒名</name>
            <url>https://github.com/lihengming/</url>
            <email>89921218@qq.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>Omega-Ariston</id>
            <name>Jiechuan Chen</name>
            <email>654815312@qq.com</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache 2</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <comments>A business-friendly OSS license</comments>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!--
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <!--
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>- -add-modules</arg>
                        <arg>java.xml.bind</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    -->
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <attach>true</attach>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/bvt/**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadoc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${javadoc.skip}</skip>
                    <show>public</show>
                    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <docencoding>UTF-8</docencoding>
                    <links>
                        <link>http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api</link>
                    </links>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${gpg.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.javaslang</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaslang</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.35</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.35</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.trove4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javamoney.moneta</groupId>
            <artifactId>moneta-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.airlift</groupId>
            <artifactId>slice</artifactId>
            <version>0.36</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.17.v20190418</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.17.v20190418</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-afterburner</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
            <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jdk-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jsoniter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoniter</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.21</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.21</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.diffblue</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeptestutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.21</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
            <version>1.21</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jackson-mapper-asl</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jackson-core-asl</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gitlab4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>gitlab4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.42</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.chinamobile.cmos</groupId>
            <artifactId>sms-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>github_actions</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.GITHUB_ACTIONS</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <!-- for codecov.io -->
                        <!-- config example: https://github.com/codecov/example-java -->
                        <!-- plugin docs: http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ -->
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8.7</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>report</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

**P.S.**: If you need more info just ask!

Comment: First upgrade the maven-compiler-plugin to the most recent one...

Comment: I've followed your advice mr @khmarbaise, but now also the cmd run fails on the testCompile goal:`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.9.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project fastjson: Error while storing the mojo status: Input length = 1`, while in Eclipse almost nothing is changed.

Comment: the linked image shows test failures... please show/post the full pom file..